# HighCharts Bullet Chart label show on top Possible?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bullet-chart

I want to show the label of this bullet chart in the top of the chart instead left side.Is it possible? 
Here is the code,

```
Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['<span class="hc-cat-title">Profit</span><br/>%']
    },
    yAxis: {
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 20,
            color: '#666'
        }, {
            from: 20,
            to: 25,
            color: '#999'
        }, {
            from: 25,
            to: 100,
            color: '#bbb'
        }],
        labels: {
            format: '{value}%'
        },
        title: null
    },
    series: [{
        data: [{
            y: 22,
            target: 27
        }]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> (with target at {point.target})'
    }
});
```

Here is the bullet chart. I want to show my Label Profit to the top of the chart.

[image]
you can also see jsfiddle: [Bullet chart](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bullet-graph/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dataLabels` property with the right options:

```
series: [{
    data: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<span class="hc-cat-title">Profit</span>',
            align: 'left',
            y: 40,
            inside: true
        },
        y: 275,
        target: 250
    }]
}]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rxkt43o7/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data.dataLabels

Comment: It show's in the opposite side. I need to show on the top... see the image on top

Comment: Hi @Shanto Siddiq, Sorry for missunderstanding your problem. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek for answering but the Label (Profit) is not showing in the tool-tip can you please help me with that?

Comment: Hi @Shanto Siddiq, No problem, you can use the `headerFormat` property for a tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vesxkp9b/